# Calculating number of operations in a divide and conquer approach when the input is not an exact power of 2

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, divide-and-conquer

Here is a divide and conquer approach for finding minimum and maximum elements in an array.

```
MaxMin(i, j, max, min)
{  
   //max and min are the references so that we can retain their value when
   //we return from the function. i and j are the indices of start and 
   //end respectively.
     if (i=j) then max := min := a[i]; //Small(P)
      else if (i=j-1) then // Another case of Small(P)
      {
            if (a[i] < a[j]) then max := a[j]; min := a[i];
            else max := a[i]; min := a[j];
      }
     else
     {
           // if P is not small, divide P into sub-problems.
           // Find where to split the set.
           mid := ( i + j )/2;
           // Solve the sub-problems.
           MaxMin( i, mid, max, min );
           MaxMin( mid+1, j, max1, min1 );
           // Combine the solutions.
           if (max < max1) then max := max1;
           if (min > min1) then min := min1;
    }
```

}

If we analyze the complexity of this algorithm, we see that if n is the power of 2, then it does (3n/2)-2 comparisons. 
My question is how many comparisons does it do if n is not an exact power of 2. I think it does more than 3n comparisons because at the base level, we are left with 3 elements(which take 3 comparisons) instead of 2 elements(which take just 1 comparison). But I am not sure about my thinking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [How do I find the max and min value of an array in 3n/2−2 comparisons?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52663/how-do-i-find-the-max-and-min-value-of-an-array-in-3n-2−2-comparisons)

Comment: Try to extend the analysis that works for powers of $2$ to general $n$, and see what you get. Also, you can try calculating the number of comparisons for small values of $n$, and then guess the general solution.